# behavior of an iterator in a Flask response

Tags: python, csv, flask, request, generator

I am struggling with the function `iter_all_rows()` below. [Here is an example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/#basic-usage) showing how to stream a large csv to your user.

```
from flask import Response

@app.route('/large.csv')
def generate_large_csv():
    def generate():
        for row in iter_all_rows():
            yield ','.join(row) + '\n'
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

**Here is my issue**

I have a list of records like

```
recs = [{'big': 200, 'small': 56, 'large': 2009}, 
        {'big': 444, 'small': 34, 'large': 7777}]
```

and I would like to serve this to the user as a `csv` file. I am trying to create the csv first, and then serve it as shown below

```
@perf.route('/_rundata.csv')
def generate_large_csv():

    recs = [{'big': 200, 'small': 56, 'large': 2009}, 
            {'big': 444, 'small': 34, 'large': 7777}]

    with open('unique-filename.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(recs)

    with open('unique-filename.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            print 'row', row 
        def generate():
            for row in reader:
                print 'grow', grow
                yield ','.join(row) + '\n'

        return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

I think I'm approaching it wrong. I've tried many combinations and one of the errors I keep getting is `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` errors before one of the `grow` instances prints

**My question**

How do I get a persistent generator that will serve the data over the life of the request? Like `iter_all_items()` in the example?

I need to get these records to the user as a csv file. Is this the best approach?

Comment: if it takes a long time to create you should probably create the csv in a seperate process and email it to the user (you can use celery or even simple multiprocessing)

Comment: I may do that, but many of these are very small. I use `celery` to serve other things, it does help a lot! At this point I am more interested in the why.

Comment: oonce you return you have left the context of the `with open...` therefor the file is closed ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley precisely my question

Comment: thats not a question thats a statement... do you mean it answers the question?

Answer (score 1):

you could try and not close the file handle (then you would not open it with the context syntax but instead)

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(csvfile,"rb"))
def generate_all():
    for row in reader:
        yield str(row)
```

....
maybe ... im not sure since i have never used a generator like this ... as a flask response ...